# Order of power of 2 and 5

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How can we find the smallest positive integer $a$ such that
$$3^a\equiv 1\mod 2^n5^m,$$ where $n,m$ are given positive integers. Generally, for any given $k$ prime numbers which are not equal to  $3$, i.e.  $p_1,p_2,\cdots, p_k$, how can we find a smallest positive integer $b$ such that
$$3^b\equiv 1\mod \Pi_{i=1}^{k} p_i^{\ell_i},$$
where $\ell_i$ are some  given positive integers.

Answer (score 1):

Use Euler theorem for $2^n$ and $5^m$.

- Let $r={\rm ord}_{2^n} (3)$. Then $3^r\equiv 1 \pmod {2^n}$ and $r\mid \phi(2^n)=2^{n-1}$.
- Similary, let $s={\rm ord}_{5^m} (3)$. Then $3^s\equiv 1 \pmod {5^m}$ and $s\mid \phi(5^m)=4\cdot 5^{m-1}$.

Then $a={\rm lcm}(s,r)$.

This can be easily generalized for arbitrary number of primes.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.  However, I want to find the exact form of $a$. For instance, whether $a=2^{n-1}\cdot 4\cdot 5^{n-1}$?

Comment: I realize that your idea is correct. The problem is to find $r=ord_{2^n}(3)$ and  $s=ord_{5^m}(3)$. Note that $r=2^{n-2}$ and $s=4\cdot 5^{m-1}$. Hence, $a=2^n5^{m-1}$.